# I am confused about PHP Post/Redirect/Get

Tags: php, html, forms, post, get

In an [article](http://kyleschaeffer.com/best-practices/10-things-a-website-should-never-ever-do/) on preventing PHP form resubmissions, I read the following:

(Not quoting) This could be the page that receives the form data, for example called "form.php":

```
<form action="submit.php">
  <input type="text" name="user" required />
  <input type="password" name="pass" required />
  <input type="submit" value="Log in" />
</form>
```

The page that would process the POST data would therefore be called "submit.php". If the login went correctly, this code would run:

```
header('Location: /login/form.php?success=true');
```

However, couldn't a user just navigate to the URL above? Also, what is the purpose of the GET variable? Couldn't I just have a script at form.php that checks if the user is logged in?

At submit.php, should I save the logged in username as **$_SESSION['username']**, and then check if *isset()* at form.php? Also, since  a URL with "success" in it isn't really pretty, is it economical to redirect the user once again? Should I use PHP header() or Javascript **window.location.href?** As you see, I'm sort of confused.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: "However, couldn't a user just navigate to the URL above?" --- yes he can. So?

Comment: You're right, without POST data no harm would be done.

Comment: Nothing is really that ugly about `?success` in the url.  I use things like that all the time, because most people don't pay attention to that and it's really easy.

Comment: I'm assuming the purpose of the query string in that example was for `form.php` to use to determine if it should display a success message. You could do this sort of thing in the session if you wanted. The important part is that there's a redirect, so a reload doesn't re-do the POST, just the harmless GET to the success page.

Comment: But why does there need to be the GET? For the success message, I could just check if the user is logged in!

Comment: @user805556: it is a general solution for any kind of form, for example for adding comment form. In that case checking that message has been successfully added is not that easy like `if (isset($_SESSION...`

Comment: @user805556 - It doesn't need to be there.  It's just there as an example of how you can pass some extra data along to the page you redirect the user to.  In the login context, it's kind of silly.  If your POST creates, say, a print job, you might want to pass ?printJobId=7 along, to avoid storing in the session and having to then manage it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> However, couldn't a user just navigate to the URL above?

Yes, he can. This will not cause anything bad though.

> Also, what is the purpose of the GET variable?

To have some flag that represents the fact that the form has been processed successfully and you need to congratulate user.

> Couldn't I just have a script at form.php that checks if the user is logged in?

Uhm, you can keep your code in the way **you like**. There is no any strong requirements

> At submit.php, should I save the logged in username as $_SESSION['username'], and then check if isset() at form.php?

If you need to persist it across the current session - yes, do so.

> Also, since a URL with "success" in it isn't really pretty, is it economical to redirect the user once again?

Redirect where. Redirection is pretty cheap thing.

> Should I use PHP header() or Javascript window.location.href?

You definitely should do that in php, otherwise you'll get the troubles you're trying to avoid following PRG-way.

Comment: Ok, that cleared it up a bit. However, since I never use separate login pages, but have them on every page, should I redirect to this:? "submit.php?page=whatever.php" and then use that variable to redirect back to that specific page? Also, how can I find out the current page in PHP, so that I can automate the process I suggested above? Thanks.

Comment: @user805556: just pass the redirect url as any other parameters and after processing - redirect back to it. Current url (or to be precise - the pieces of current url) you can find at `$_SERVER`

Answer (score 3):

PRG or Post/Redirect/Get is just a pattern you can use to prevent the message boxes. How you use it in detail (and the article does only a generic suggestion) depends on your needs.

If you want to flag the success flash message inside a cookie or a session or a get variable, that's totally up to you. A second redirect won't help btw, you'll learn that if you play around with it.

The only important part is, that after you have received the POST request, you do the redirect. The user then can still move back and forward in history w/o being asked to re-submit POST data.

The pattern works and is a fine thing. Just two days ago I did it again and a step-by-step weppapp installer was much nicer to navigate with the browser interface.

**About your redirect**

This code is wrong:

```
header('Location:/login/form.php?success=true');
```

First of all, you need to have a space after the colon:

```
header('Location: /login/form.php?success=true');
```

Then the address must be an absolute URI, it must contain the full URL:

```
header('Location: http://example.com/login/form.php?success=true');
```

Next to the `header()`, you should provide a message body as per RFC, many so called "web-developers" don't even know:

```
$url = 'http://example.com/login/form.php?success=true';
header(sprintf('Location: %s', $url));
printf('<a href="%s">Moved</a>.', $url);
exit;
```

Don't forget the exit. Sure, that's pretty much re-enventing the wheel, instead install the http extension of PHP and just do this line:

```
http_redirect('/login/form.php?success=true');
```

You find that [nifty helper here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-redirect.php).

To recap: Important is that you do the redirect after post. Everything else, like passing a variable is totally up to you how you would like to do it.

Comment: @user805556: please click: [`sprintf`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php)

Comment: No, there is no need for it to be an absolute URI, or even a rooted path.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should never rely on a GET variable (or even a hidden POST variable) to say, "sure, let me in, I'm a valid user!".

Personally, I would strip the GET information from the link and rely solely on session variables. Remember to place a 'session_start();' as the first line of code if you are using PHP to activate the session.

For submit.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
if ($_POST['user'] && $_POST['pass']) { // Make sure both variable are set
 if (your_method) {
 // Code to check if the user and pass are valid however you plan
  $_SESSION['user'] = $_POST['user'];
  $_SESSION['loggedin'] = time();
 }
}
header('Location: form.php'); // Either way, pass or fail, return to form.php
exit();
?>
```

Then in form.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
$activeuser = false;
if ($_SESSION['user'] && $_SESSION['loggedin'] < (time()+600)) {
// Check if the user exists and the last access was with in 10 minutes.
 $_SESSION['loggedin'] = time(); // If so, keep them up to date!
 $activeuser = true;
}
if ($activeuser) {
 // whatever should show to someone logged in
} else {
 // Show log in form
}
?>
```

Also, you may already know this, but the default method of transferring is GET, so be sure to specify method="post" in the form tag.

It's normally best to use header() to redirect if needed as Javascript is client-side and can be avoided which can break your intent for the functioning of your site.

Answer (score 1):

The main idea behind POST/REDIRECT/GET, as the article you linked to points out, is to avoid users resubmitting data (most of the time).  Generally, you don't want the same POST (with the exact same data) to happen twice -- indeed, in some situations, it could end up performing some action (like charging a credit card) a second time, which would be bad.

Most of what you ask about in your question are implementation details (like sending the ?success request parameter in the redirect).

In practice, what usually happens is that your redirect **on success**.  If, for example, the user's input fails validation, you *don't redirect*, and instead, redisplay the form, along with relevant error messages.

Here's a basic example, all in one script.  I've tried to include only what's important, with as little extraneous stuff as possible.

**login.php**

```
<?php
/**
 * ensure user supplied both username & password
 * @return mixed true or an array of error messages
 */ 
function validate_login_values($vars){
    $errors = array();
    if (empty($vars['username'])) $errors[] = 'You must supply a username, genius.';
    if (empty($vars['password'])) $errors[] = 'You must supply a password, dummy.';
    if (empty($errors)) return true;
    return $errors; // $errors must be an array.
}

if (! empty($_POST)){
    $validationResults = validate_login_values($_POST);
    if ($validationResults === true){
        // assume here that authenticate properly escapes it's arguments before sending them
        // to the database.
        if (authenticate($_POST['username'],$_POST['password'])){
            //GREAT SUCCESS!  The user is now logged in.  Redirect to home page
            header("Location: /");
            die();
        }
        $errors[] = 'Invalid username/password.  Try again, slim";

    }else{
        $errors = $validationResults; // validate_login_values created errors.
    }  
}
?>

<h1>Log In, Friend!</h1>]

<?php 
//display errors, if there were any
if (! empty($errors)): ?>
<div class="errors">Something went horribly wrong:
<ul><?php foreach($errors as $e) echo "<li>$e</li>"; ?></ul>
<div>
<?php endif; ?>

<form method="POST">
<!--   //username, password, and submit   -->
</form>
```

Comment: A question: When I redirect a user with header() and then echo, where does the stuff get echoed? At the top?