# Optional Form - How do I remove the "this page has used data..." message?

Tags: php, html, forms, header

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [I am confused about PHP Post/Redirect/Get](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7681755/i-am-confused-about-php-post-redirect-get)

I have a form on a page, so I get the "this page has used data, are you sure you want to refresh" message when I reload the page.

I looked into the HTTP-303 response code, which gets rid of the message (I'm on Chrome btw) until I submit the form once, and then it starts bugging me again.

Basically, I have an optional "contact me" form, that shouldn't throw a prompt if the page is refreshed. I don't think/see why I should need a separate page for submission for a short form like this. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: There are many posts about post/redirect/get that you may want to read. Here's one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7681755/i-am-confused-about-php-post-redirect-get

Comment: @DarylGill that's it: `header('HTTP/1.1 303 Optional Form');` and searches for anything like "optional form resubmit" don't get me anywhere

Comment: @KaiQing I said I don't want to redirect. It's a small "contact me form" (leave me a message) that at most shows a "succesfully submitted" or "error: ..." on the same page. There's no page to go to afterwards, no result to show.

Comment: the redirect reloads the page so you don't get the browser default message warning you about a re-post. If you think your form is so small then why not submit it via ajax and circumvent this problem entirely?

Comment: Additionally, the reload in this case is no less transparent to the user than the initial form post anyhow, so why avoid it?

Comment: I'm getting strange things with the `header('Location: ...')`... it doesn't seem to reload/submit the page at all (I'm redirecting to the same page). I hadn't thought of Ajax, but before I close this is there any way to submit a form to the same page, without getting the "this page requested data..." message? **Edit** I realized you probably meant create a new processing page, and redirect to the original one. Cool for me, I'll try it out.

Comment: No, I meant to make the action blank or $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] - as in <form action="" method="post"> - this assumes your form processing is at the top of the file before any output is written to the browser

Comment: @KaiQing It's the same - no message when I refresh, but if I submit the form, then refresh, it keeps prompting me. Plus, In one of the threads, it said you shouldn't leave out the `action` in HTML5

Comment: Ah fixed, it was just URL problems because I was using my local host.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best option is to use [Ajax](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp). That way you don't need to reload.
I usually use it with [JQuery](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/default.asp).
So you end up with something like:

```
function send_message(vMessage,vWho) {
    $.ajax({
        url:"messageSender.php",
        data:{message:vMessage,from:vWho},
        type:"POST",
        success:function(result) {
            // DO SOMETHING HERE, LIKE AN ALERT
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Accepted as an answer, but in case anyone wants the intended solution, (prevent resubmission, but without other scripts), see my final solution below

Answer (score 1):

**Final Solution:
How to prevent form resubmission, on the same page**

1. You should have the `action="something"` tag. Required in HTML5
2. Check if a form was submitted. If you don't, and have a `header('Location: ...')` it will be like an infinite loop (crap out). So something like `if (isset($_POST['some_submit_btn'])) {`
3. Do you processing logic
4. Do `header('Location: same_page')` (eg: `header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])`) and `exit`

Your page can now refresh regularly, even after submitting a form. The redirect clears the POST request or whatever.

Others have pointed out Ajax is a simpler solution. I've accepted it as an answer, but in case anyone wants to do it this way I put this for reference.

**Note**: If you want to pass data between the two pages/refreshes, you have to pass it through sessions or cookies (I prefer sessions). I don't think there's a "clean" workaround

Answer (score 0):

You need to redirect after you saved the form data. It can be done on the same page, it's not a problem, you just need to issue a GET request instead of a POST.

Comment: It's a 'leave me a message' form. Passing the entire message through get doesn't seem elegant..

Comment: Yeah I agree. The answer is not to use get. But rather to either capture post, then reload the referring page or submit it via ajax to avoid a page load

Comment: What I meant is doing a redirect to issue a GET after the POST.